# Locally constant group schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$, then the group scheme $\mu_\ell$, if $p$ does not divide $\ell$, is étale-locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}$. I have two quick questions which I don't feel very certain. Is $\mu_p$ fppf locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $? Also, is $\alpha_p $ fppf locally constant?

Answer (score 5):

**AlexL**'s answer is a good one, I just want to point out another thought process.

Let $G$ be a finite group scheme over $X$ any scheme. If $G$ is fppf locally on $X$ constant then, in particular, the morphism $G\to X$ is fppf locally on $X$ etale since, after all, the constant group scheme is etale over its base. But, whether a morphism is etale can be checked fppf locally (e.g. see [1, Tag02VN]). Thus, if $G$ is locally constant then $G\to X$ is etale. The schemes $\mu_p\to\text{Spec}(k)$ and $\alpha_p\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ are not etale if $p = \mathrm{char}(k)$ and thus cannot be locally constant.

*Remark 1:* Of course, you can also replace 'fppf' by 'fpqc' as the above link shows.

*Remark 2:* The moral of the discussion in the comments to this answer/the answer of Qiaochu's is that if $k$ is a field then something happening fppf/fpqc locally on $k$ implies that this thing already happens over $\overline{k}$ (in fact it's iff for fpqc and iff fppf for most reasonable things that behave well with limits--one gets a similar statement where something which plays nicely with limits happens smooth locally, e.g. in the sense of [1, Tag021Z], over $k$ iff it happens over $k^\mathrm{sep}$).

Thus, if two group schemes $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic fppf/fpqc locally on $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ then, in fact, $G_{\overline{k}}$ and $G'_{\overline{k}}$ are isomorphic. The point is then that this clearly doesn't happen if $G=\underline{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ and $G'=\mu_p$ or $G'=\alpha_p$ as can be checked in a variety of ways:

1. They don't have isomorphic $\overline{k}$-points (e.g. $G(\overline{k})$ has size $p$ but $G'(\overline{k})$ is trivial for either choice of $G'$).
2. The schemes $G_{\overline{k}}$ and $G'_{\overline{k}}$ aren't even isomorphic--$G_{\overline{k}}$ is reduced but $G'_{\overline{k}}$ is not reduced (for either choice of $G'$).
3. ...

The above answer I gave works more generally for any base whereas this argument in the comments to this answer/Qiaochu's answer aren't really generalizable in an easy way.

[1] Various authors, 2020. *Stacks project*. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/

Comment: Alex, help an old colleague out: can you tell me in as concrete terms as possible what "fppf locally isomorphic" means? Does it mean that there exists an fppf covering such that we have isomorphisms after base change to each element in the cover?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, it just means that there exists an fppf cover $Y\to X$ such that $G_Y$ is ______.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to be able to get my hands on this question concretely if possible. Never got around to learning about sites...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You don't need to understand in terms of sites in general, but for this specific question there's an even easier explanation.  Suppose that $\mu_p\to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is fppf locally constant. Then, the same is true for $\mu_p\to\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k})$ so we can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. So if $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is an fppf cover such that $\mu_{p,X}$ we'd get issues. Why? Since being constant is preserved under passing to an open subset we can assume that $X\to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is actually finite presentation. Which, since $k$ is algebraically

Comment: closed means that it has a section. So then one would see that base changing $\mu_p$ along this section would show that $\mu_p$ is constant. Oops.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Does that make you happy? :P

Comment: I actually understood your first argument more! I think I follow your second argument (modulo assuming various background details about how covers work) up until the last step: "base changing $\mu_p$ along this section would show that $\mu_p$ is constant."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Let's write $G$ for $\mu_p$ over $k$. If $G_X$ were constant and $s:\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to X$ were a section of $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ then $G_X\times_{X,s}\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ would be constant (since base change of constant is constant), but this fiber product, since $s$ is a section, is just $G$ based changed along $\mathrm{Spec}(k)\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}}\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ which is just $G$. So, $G$ would be constant. Again, oopsie. Also, no theory of covers used. Just theory of base change.

Comment: Aha, thank you, it's clear now. I'm about to post a more simple-minded answer; would appreciate if you checked it over to see if I've unwound the definitions properly.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I've unwound the definitions properly: it sounds to me like to check whether two things are fppf-locally isomorphic over $\text{Spec } k$ it suffices to check whether or not there exists some finitely presented $k$-algebra $A$ (flatness and surjectivity of $\text{Spec } A \to \text{Spec } k$ being automatic) such that the extensions of scalars to $A$ are isomorphic. Do I have that right?

If so, we can show that $\mu_{p, A} \cong \text{Spec } A[x]/(x^p - 1)$ is never isomorphic to the constant group scheme $\text{Spec } A^{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$; in fact already they are never isomorphic as $A$-schemes, forgetting the group structure. I will be very explicit here for those reading along who, like me, are not true algebraic geometers! Since every finitely presented $A$ admits a map to $\bar{k}$, it suffices to show this for $A = \overline{k}$, and then we can just take $\bar{k}$-points and observe that $\mu_{p, \overline{k}}$ has only one $\bar{k}$-point but $\text{Spec } \bar{k}^{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ has, of course, $p$ of them.

Similarly we can show that $\alpha_p$ is not locally constant by checking that $\alpha_{p, A} \cong \text{Spec } A[x]/x^p$ is never isomorphic to any constant group scheme, which is already true forgetting the group structure. Again it suffices to show this for $A = \bar{k}$ and then again taking $\bar{k}$-points shows that there's one of them, so if $\alpha_{p, A}$ were locally constant it would have to be locally isomorphic to a point and it's not. (And of course since $x^p - 1 \cong (x - 1)^p$ we have that $\mu_p$ and $\alpha_p$ have the same underlying scheme.)

Comment: Yep, this seems totally fine. It's essentially the second argument I was mentioning in the the comments to my answer.

Comment: @Alex: thanks for checking!

Answer (score 2):

I guess if $\mu_p$ were locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, there would be a $k$-algebra $A$ such that $\mu_{p,A}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}_A$. But for a field $K$ which is a $A$-algebra, $\mu_{p,A}(K)=1$ but $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}_A(K)$ is the abstract group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$